# Connect Spyder to a console in a docker container on a remote host

Tags: python, docker, spyder

I am using a docker on a remote AWS EC2 instance to run my code. My current workflow is to edit code on a local machine, push it to git and then log into the EC2 machine and the docker container in it, to pull the code and run it. I was wondering if I could somehow attach Spyder's console to the kernel inside the docker, in the EC2 instance.

So my sequence of log-ins are:

`localhost~:  ssh -XYA remote-ec2.domain.ext
remote-ec2~: ssh -XYA root@localhost -p 2222
(docker)~: python runme.py`

I found a tutorial to [use an SSH](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel) connected kernel, but I am wondering how to tunnel through to the docker inside.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how you solved this problem? I am having trouble with the same issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is possible and not that hard. Please read [our documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel) on how to achieve it.

Comment: Hi @carlos-cordoba - I am having unable to achieve this using the linked documentation (for an elaboration see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57138289/connecting-spyder-to-remote-jupyter-notebook-in-a-docker-container). Could you please give an example of how this could be achieved in the answers?